# how to convert a string variable to dictionary

Tags: python

I use python and I would like to know how to convert a **string** variable that contains :

```
"OrderedDict([('bagging_freq', 2), ('colsample_bytree', 0.98), ('learning_rate', 0.13)])"
```

to a **dictionary** variable :

```
{'bagging_freq': 2, 'colsample_bytree': 0.98, 'learning_rate': 0.13}
```

Comment: How did you get the original string in the first place? Perhaps you are trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: Sounds like something that should be fixed at the source.

Comment: it generated when i used bayes_search_cv for getting best parameters, i stor the list of parameters in csv file the i use the last column that contain list of parameters , it is filled by this formulation

Answer (score 1):

One easy way would be to use `eval`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
s = "OrderedDict([('bagging_freq', 2), ('colsample_bytree', 0.98), ('learning_rate', 0.13)])"
s = eval(s) 

# this results in : 
#     OrderedDict([('bagging_freq', 2),
#            ('colsample_bytree', 0.98),
#            ('learning_rate', 0.13)])

# now, if you'd like to convert that to a 'regular' duct, just do:
dict(s)
```

Output:

```
{'bagging_freq': 2, 'colsample_bytree': 0.98, 'learning_rate': 0.13}
```

*** Please note that eval is *really* unsafe from a security perspective ***

Comment: in my case i wouldn(t convert an orderdict to string but i have already a string var that contains this text "OrderedDict([('bagging_freq', 2),...])" and i want to convert it to a sample dictionary